# Playback a sound file somehow into the bridged call's both side at same time?

Tags: asterisk, playback, pbx

I would like to create a greeting sound playback service for the PBX agents.
The scenario is simple. When **A** calls **B** agent  and **B** agent pick up the phone the system should play an audio file into the bridged call's both side at same time (for example: "Greeting! My name is Bob. How can I help you?"). The focus is on the "same time", but of course a few milliseconds difference acceptable.
I have been thinking about it for hours without any breakthrough.
I tried the ChanSpy with *B* option but it does not work as I want.

Any suggestions? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two chanspy work ok for this type of task. One play to A, other to B

Also work ok transfer both to conference.

And playback to both via features.conf also work okay.

Comment: Thanks!
I had network problems therefore the ChanSpy whispering into the A call leg didn't work, but now, after some corrections the _B_ option forks fine. Of course the simply chanspy (w option) whispering also a good idea.
My real scenario much more complex than I mentioned. I use Queues with LocalChannels. I tried to use the feature codes, but the local channels broke it.